# How to POST request with parameters using Alamofire/URLSession.dataTask in swift

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, nsurlsession

I have tried two methods to POST request to call API. `Alamofire` & `URLSession.dataTask` but I m unable to send parameters successfully.

These are my tried approaches

**Parameters**

```
var params :[String: AnyObject]?
    params = ["Some_ID" : "53" as AnyObject, "REQUEST" : "SOME_API_NAME" as AnyObject]
```

**ONE --> Alamofire**

```
Alamofire.request(BaseURL, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in

        switch(response.result) {
        case .success(_):
            if response.result.value != nil{
                print(response.result.value as Any)
            }
            break

        case .failure(_):
            print(response.result.error as Any)
            break
        }
    }
```

**TWO --> URLSession.dataTask**

```
    if let theJSONData = try? JSONSerialization.data(
        withJSONObject: params as Any,
        options: []) {
        let theJSONText = String(data: theJSONData,
                                 encoding: .ascii)
        print("JSON string = \(theJSONText!)")

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: URL(string:BaseURL)!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        //Here are the required Params.
        let postString = theJSONText

        request.httpBody = postString?.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)


        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { data, response, error in
            guard error == nil && data != nil else {                                                          // check for fundamental networking error

                print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
                return
            }

            if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {
                print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                print("response = \(String(describing: response))")
                return
            }
            let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!
            let responseStringForJson = "[\(responseString)]"

            print("result = \(String(describing: responseStringForJson))")

        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

In both cases I m facing the same Issue. API called and reach to server successfully, but server return the error **Request parameter is missing**.

And interesting thing is, API is working and responding in POSTMAN and using AFNetworking in my Objective-C code.

Please tell me what I m doing wrong here...

Comment: you should use `[String: Any]` & avoid cast

Comment: Okay, but tried with this too.

Comment: Maybe you are missing Endpoint? `Alamofire.request(BaseURL+Endpoints` ?

Comment: Use `request.httpBody = theJSONData`. There is useless conversions and not the same (one is in ASCII, the other in UTF8): Dict => Data => String => Data. Avoid `NSMutableURLRequest` in Swift 3+, prefers `URLRequest` and that even should avoid the cast afterwards `request as URLRequest`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your second approach (URLSession.dataTask) and get the POST string from parameters dictionary like this. Hope this will work in your case.

Try below code and let me know. For now call `getDataFromAPI` from `viewDidLoad` and test.

```
func getPostString(params:[String:Any]) -> String
{
    var data = [String]()
    for(key, value) in params
    {
        data.append(key + "=\(value)")
    }
    return data.map { String($0) }.joined(separator: "&")
}

func getDataFromAPI() {

    var params :[String: Any]?
    params = ["Some_ID" : "111", "REQUEST" : "SOME_API_NAME"]

    let url =  URL(string:BaseURL)
    var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    let postString = getPostString(params: params!)
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { data, response, error in
        guard error == nil && data != nil else {
            print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
            return
        }
        if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {
            print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
            print("response = \(String(describing: response))")
            return
        }
        let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!
        let responseStringForJson = "[\(responseString)]"
        print("result = \(String(describing: responseStringForJson))")
    }
    task.resume()
}
```